# Feature specs for exceptional scenarios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I read that controller specs are going out of favor and that the current recommendation is to use feature and request specs. I've found feature specs have been working really well for happy path testing, but I'm having some difficulty with exceptional cases I want to test. For instance I have an index of resources owned by a user. This list includes buttons to destroy each resource. Users only see their own resources. I want to add a test that attempting to destroy one that belongs to someone else fails. The problem is that the list won't include anybody else's items so there isn't an appropriate link to tell capybara to click. In a controller test I could directly issue a `DELETE` on the resource's path, but as best I can tell that is not an option in feature specs. Am I missing something? Do I need to implement request specs too if I want coverage outside the happy path? I was hoping to reserve request specs for covering my API endpoints.

Comment: I am just curious, but can you share a link about 'controller specs are going out of favor and that the current recommendation is to use feature and request specs'?

Comment: https://everydayrails.com/2016/08/29/replace-rspec-controller-tests.html this mentions both the rails and rspec team recommending against them. Some of the helpers to support controller tests were also removed in rails 5.

Comment: I would actually disagree with the article you linked in comment and I don't see anything wrong with continuing to carry out controller tests - what exactly is the problem with ensuring a controller actions logic is working as intended and its output (instance variables) is being generated correctly in isolation from the rest of the system. Incidentally `assigns` and `assert_template` are available in a separate gem (`rails-controller-testing`.

Comment: @David What are pros of controller specs in comparison with request specs?

Comment: Well imho I see controller tests as more like unit tests that enable you to identify and isolate errors more easily - request specs are more like integration tests which involve everything (router, middleware stack, rack requests and responses) which may make it more difficult to track down any issue should they arise (btw, I'm not suggesting that request/integration tests don't have their use)

Comment: @David Of course it's up to your or my practice, but to be honest full stack is what I was really missing in controller spec. At least I've always added `render_views` for all my `GET` controller specs, because without checking view for stacktraces such test misses too many errors and bugs

Comment: Sorry I didn't check back in on this question earlier. What I ended up doing was covering the DELETE behavior in a request spec. After reading this conversation though I'm probably going to change it to a controller test. Doing it as request didn't buy me anything and I'm more concerned with the behavior of the controller in isolation than the rest of the stack. Since my question doesn't have a straight forward answer I'm going to accept @AntonTkachov's answer since its clear at least that permissions shouldn't be handled in the feature spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, permission specs should NOT be implemented as feature specs. Your thoughts fully makes sense and the only one thing you can really check there is that you DON'T see any entities, that were made by other users. Your logical difficulties is like +1 point, that such scenarios should be tested via another spec types. Also... feature specs are expensive and I would never do such 'deep' test in features.

Comment: I would disagree with what you say regarding "the only one thing you can really check there is that you DON'T see any entities" - an authorised user acting maliciously could easily attempt to DELETE a resource that they can't see and does not belong to them - you really should have authentication on the resource and test for such scenarios.

Comment: @David Do you really test DELETE with feature specs? You can always do that with request spec with absolutely same quality, but with better speed

Comment: think I misunderstood ... I was talking from the perspective of controller testing.. I thought you were indicating that it's not necessary to test for authorisation at all.

Comment: I mean that it's no real need to test authorisation as a heavy intergration test